# Getting inconsistent API response from Firebase function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I've wrote an API with Firebase functions.

When I'm *testing locally*
`firebase serve --only functions`, giving a URL as: `http://localhost:5000/my-project/us-central1/app`

and `firebase serve --only function,hosting` giving the URL: `http://localhost:5000` I get the responses that I'm expecting, but when I *deploy* my code (`firebase deploy`) some routes stop working.
After deploying once again without changing my code, the routes that previously worked are now broken and the broken ones are now working.

Using *Postman* to send the request to my API.
testing example:

```
http://localhost:5000/my-project/us-central1/app/foo/bar
```

when: `https://my-project.web.app/foo/bar`
The error: `Cannot GET /api/articles`

index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

const api = require('./routes/api');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());

app.use('/api', api.router);

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

api.js

```
const express = require('express');
const url = require('url');
const articlesRepo = require('../data/articlesRepo');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/articles', (req, res)=>{
    articlesRepo.getAllArticles((err, articles)=>{
        if (err) res.status(400).json(err.message);
        res.json(articles);
    });
});

router.get('/articles/find', (req, res)=>{
    const queryObject = url.parse(req.url,true).query;

    articlesRepo.findArticlesByName(queryObject, (err, articles)=>{
        if (err) res.status(400).json(err.message);
        res.json(articles);
    });
});

module.exports = {
    router,
};
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

> Edit
>   After checking once again the broken route I got a new anser:

`getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN my-database-host-url:3306`

> Edit #2

I don't know why the strange behavior by Functions but I've found out that the last error I got was because I'm trying to send traffic to a server that is not google and this is not allowed by google itself unless you don't want to pay for their Spark or other plans.

I suspect that the issues at the beginning where connected to this fact.

Comment: How exactly are you testing locally, and how is that different than production?  Please edit the question to be **very specific** about your procedure, including the URLs you use, and how you use the emulator.

Comment: I've edited now, speifically I use "firebase serve --only functions" or "functions,hosting"

Comment: **Please be specific**, and include the URLs you're using, even if just a pattern.  Invoking the function via Hosting is going to be different than invoking the function directly via Cloud Functions because of the way the URL rewrite works.  My guess is that you're not using Hosting during emulation, but you are in prod.

Comment: Ok, I've added them too. firebase serve --only functions, giving a URL as: http://localhost:5000/my-project/us-central1/app and firebase serve --only function,hosting giving the URL: http://localhost:5000